# Pattern matching against typeclass instances in Haskell function

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm attempting to write a data-processing module in Haskell that accepts `changesets` relating to different schemas, and passes these through a series of rules that optionally perform actions based on the data. (This is mostly an academic exercise to get a better understanding of Haskell)

To better explain what I'm doing, here's a working example in Scala

```scala
// We have an open type allowing us to define arbitrary 'Schemas' 
// in other packages.
trait Schema[T]

// Represents a changeset in response to user action - i.e. inserting some records into a database.
sealed trait Changeset[T]
case class Insert[T]( schema:Schema[T], records:Seq[T]) extends Changeset[T]
case class Update[T]( schema:Schema[T], records:Seq[T]) extends Changeset[T]
case class Delete[T]( schema:Schema[T], records:Seq[T]) extends Changeset[T]


// Define a 'contacts' module containing a custom schema. 
package contacts {
    object Contacts extends Schema[Contact]
    case class Contact( firstName:String, lastName:String )   
}

// And an 'accounts' module
package accounts {
    object Accounts extends Schema[Account]
    case class Account( name:String )
}


// We now define an arbitrary number of rules that each
// changeset will be checked against
trait Rule {
    def process( changeset: Changeset[_] ):Unit
}

// As a contrived example, this rule keeps track of the 
// number of contacts on an account
object UpdateContactCount extends Rule {
    // To keep it simple let's pretend we're doing IO directly here
    def process( changeset: Changeset[_] ):Unit = changeset match {

        // Type inference correctly infers the type of `xs` here.
        case Insert( Contacts, xs ) => ??? // Increment the count
        case Delete( Contacts, xs ) => ??? // Decrement the count
        case Insert( Accounts, xs ) => ??? // Initialize to zero
        case _ => () // Don't worry about other cases 
    }
}

val rules = [UpdateContactCount, AnotherRule, SomethingElse]
```

The important thing is that both 'Schema' and 'Rule' are open for extension, and this part specifically is throwing a bit of a curveball in my attempt at doing this in Haskell.

What I have so far in Haskell is

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

-- In this example, Schema is not open for extension.
-- I'd like it to be    
data Schema t where
    Accounts :: Schema Account
    Contacts :: Schema Contact

data Account = Account { name :: String } deriving Show
data Contact = Contact { firstName :: String, lastName :: String } deriving Show

data Changeset t = Insert (Schema t) [t]                             
                 | Update (Schema t) [t]
                 | Delete (Schema t) [t]



-- Whenever a contact is inserted or deleted, update the counter
-- on the account. (Or, for new accounts, set to zero)
-- For simplicity let's pretend we're doing IO directly here.
updateContactCount :: Changeset t -> IO ()
updateContactCount (Insert Contacts contacts) = ???
updateContactCount (Delete Contacts contacts) = ???
updateContactCount (Insert Accounts accounts) = ???
updateContactCount other = return ()
```

This example works fine - but I'd like to expand on this such that both `Schema` can be an open type (i.e. I don't know all the possibilities ahead of time), while also doing the same thing for the rules. i.e. I don't know about the `updateContactCount` function head of time, I'm simply passed a list of type `[Rule]`. i.e. something like.

```
type Rule = Changeset -> IO ()
rules = [rule1, rule2, rule3]
```

My first attempt was by creating a `Schema` typeclass instead, however Haskell still insists on locking down the function to a single type. Data kinds appears to have the same restriction.

From this, I really have two specific questions.

1. Is it possible to create a function that can pattern match against an open type, like we can in Scala?
2. Is there a more elegant idiomatic way of handling the above scenario in Haskell?

Comment: Do you mean `rules :: [Rule]`, rather than `=`?

Comment: Nope. I meant `rules = [rule1, rule2, rule3]`. I see my typo - will amend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same thing in Haskell with `Data.Typeable`.  This is not particularly natural Haskell code, suggesting you might have a very deep [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) in disguise[1], but it is a close translation of your Scala code.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable (Typeable, gcast)
import Control.Applicative ((<|>), empty, Alternative)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

-- The Schema typeclass doesn't require any functionality above and
-- beyond Typeable, but we probably want users to be required to
-- implement for explicitness.
class Typeable a => Schema a where

-- A changeset contains an existentially quantified list, i.e. a [t]
-- for some t in the Schema typeclass
data Changeset = forall t. Schema t => Insert [t]
               | forall t. Schema t => Update [t]
               | forall t. Schema t => Delete [t]

data Contact = Contact  { firstName :: String
                        , lastName  :: String }
               deriving Typeable
instance Schema Contact where

data Account = Account { name :: String }
               deriving Typeable
instance Schema Account where

-- We somehow have to let the type inferer know the type of the match,
-- either with an explicit type signature (which here requires
-- ScopedTypeVariables) or by using the value of the match in a way
-- which fixes the type.
--
-- You can fill your desired body here.
updateContactCount :: Changeset -> IO ()
updateContactCount c = choiceIO $ case c of
  Insert xs -> [ match xs (\(_ :: [Contact]) ->
                                putStrLn "It was an insert contacts")
               , match xs (\(_ :: [Account]) ->
                                putStrLn "It was an insert accounts") ]
  Delete xs -> [ match xs (\(_ :: [Contact]) ->
                                putStrLn "It was a delete contacts") ]
  _         -> []

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ updateContactCount [ Insert [Contact "Foo" "Bar"]
                                , Insert [Account "Baz"]
                                , Delete [Contact "Quux" "Norf"]
                                , Delete [Account "This one ignored"]
                                ]
```

It requires these helper combinators.

```hs
choice :: Alternative f => [f a] -> f a
choice = foldr (<|>) empty

maybeIO :: Maybe (IO ()) -> IO ()
maybeIO = fromMaybe (return ()) 

choiceIO :: [Maybe (IO ())] -> IO ()
choiceIO = maybeIO . choice

match :: (Typeable a1, Typeable a) => [a1] -> ([a] -> b) -> Maybe b
match xs = flip fmap (gcast xs)
```

The result is

```
ghci> main
It was an insert contacts
It was an insert accounts
It was a delete contacts
```

[1] This is me being opinionated.  I don't like the Scala approach of "open types" here, largely because types are not first class.  This is just an attempt to twist them to become more first class.

Comment: Thanks. I think your assertion is correct - the problem is framed too much based on an existing OO solution. I'm keen to figure a more natural way, so I might pare it back to the underlying problem and see if something more appropriate pops out.